# How Do I Search For Struct Items In A Vector?

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I'm attempting to create an inventory system using a vector implementation, but I seem to be having some troubles. I'm running into issues using a struct I made. NOTE: This isn't actually in a game code, this is a separate Solution I am using to test my knowledge of vectors and structs!

```
struct aItem
{
    string  itemName;
    int     damage;
};

int main()
{
    aItem healingPotion;
    healingPotion.itemName = "Healing Potion";
    healingPotion.damage= 6;

    aItem fireballPotion;
    fireballPotion.itemName = "Potion of Fiery Balls";
    fireballPotion.damage = -2;

    vector<aItem> inventory;
    inventory.push_back(healingPotion);
    inventory.push_back(healingPotion);
    inventory.push_back(healingPotion);
    inventory.push_back(fireballPotion);

    if(find(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), fireballPotion) != inventory.end())
                {
                        cout << "Found";
                }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The preceeding code gives me the following error:

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xutility(3186): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'aItem' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

There is more to the error, if you need it please let me know. I bet it's something small and silly, but I've been thumping at it for over two hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you use vector<aItem*> and push_back(&healingPotion) your problem will go away. this will also allow you to subclass aItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method does not know how to compare two `aItem` objects for equality.  You need to define the `==` operator in your struct definition, like this:

```
bool operator==(aItem other)
{
    if (itemName == other.itemName && damage == other.damage)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This will allow `find` to determine if two `aItem` objects are equal, which is necessary for the algorithm to work.

Comment: Whenever you write `if (c) return true; else return false;`, just write `return c;`.

Comment: Of course.  Just looking to maximize clarity.  Would you suggest always providing the best code in answers, or do you think it's sometimes worthwhile to keep things simpler to ensure the person asking the question understands the answer, especially the part relevant to the question?

Comment: Maximizing clarity means omitting noise. So yeah, maximal clarity is good, unnecessary branches is bad.

Comment: I can't disagree with that, but I would think that to a beginner, the explicit (albeit superfluous) branches are easier to understand, which allows them to focus on the core of the topic - in this case, operator overloading.

Comment: For my $.02, I don't mind the else return false, as I may not have known that you don't have to do that- newbies like me seem to get dumber and dumber, remember, as you get smarter and smarter. :)

Answer (score 5):

`find` looks for something that's equal to the item in the vector. You say you want to search using strings, but you haven't written code for that; it's trying to compare the entire struct. And you haven't written code to compare entire structs, so it's giving you an error.

The simplest solution is to use an explicit loop instead of `find`.

If you want to `find` things by string, use the `find_if` variant and write a predicate function that looks at the string. Or if you want to `find` things by the entire struct you can define an `operator ==` on the struct that compares both `itemName` and `damage`.

Or you might also consider using the `map` or `unordered_map` data structures instead of `vector`. The map containers are designed for fast lookup using a key (such as the string).

Comment: Sorry, my "string" comment was merely designed to let people know I had successfully searched while looking for strings, but once I switched to struct items, it stopped working. Sorry I wasn't clear!

Comment: +1 for 'The simplest solution is to use an explicit loop instead of find.' It's not worth jumping through the hoops to try and get find working with anything but direct comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct item {
    item(string const name,int const damage):name_(name),damage_(damage) {

    }
    string name_;
    int damage_;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<item *> items;
    item healingPostion("cure light",-10);
    item fireballPostion("fireball",10);
    items.push_back(&healingPostion);
    items.push_back(&fireballPostion);
    if(find(items.begin(), items.end(), &fireballPostion) != items.end()) {
        cout << "Found";
    }
    return 0;
}
```